# Can i get variable from php to my windows form?

Tags: c#, php, windows, winforms, variables

Is it possible to get variable from php page to use it in my windows form?

Comment: you mean to say that you want the value stored in a php variable to be stored in a C# desktop application?

Comment: @Coding-Freak yea exactly is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of emitting HTML with your .PHP file, emit a single value.

```
<?php
  echo $MyVar;
?>
```

Then, with your application, fire off an HTTPRequest to the PHP page. Then, convert the string in the HTTP Response to the data type of the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a variable you can write an xml as an page output and that can be used on windows form using [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) and [HttpWebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.aspx) classes.

Comment: this thing can be a comment instead of an answer.